# unsigned char array of 8 bits to unsigned char

Tags: c, char, bit, unsigned-char

I've created a function that turns an unsigned char into an unsigned char array of size 8 (where each index contains either 0 or 1, making up the 8 bits of the given char). Here is the 100% working version:

```
unsigned char * ucharToBitArray(unsigned char c)
{
   unsigned char * bits = malloc(8);

   int i;
   for(i=sizeof(unsigned char)*8; i; c>>=1)
       bits[--i] = '0'+(c&1);

   return bits ;
}
```

I need to create a function that does the exact opposite of this now. Meaning, it will take and unsigned char array of size 8, and turn it into a regular single unsigned char. What is an effective way of doing so?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: reverse the operations. essentially `c<<=1;c|=b[i++]-'0'`

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, you need `i = CHAR_BIT`

Comment: Or... you could just boldly type out 8 in the code and then hang yourself the day you encounter a system where one byte doesn't have 8 bits.

Comment: @David Baez: Note: malloc is returning memory in Byte size. So you aren't really converting an array of 8 bits. you are converting a array of 64 bits, where each byte is representing a bit. To directly convert the bits, you had to use `bit fields`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is needlessly complex and obscure. I would suggest replacing it with this:

```
void ucharToBitArray(char bits[8], uint8_t c)
{
   for(uint8_t i=0; i<8; i++)
   {
     if(c & (1<<i))
     {
       bits[7-i] = '1';
     }
     else
     {
       bits[7-i] = '0';
     }
   }
}
```

Now to convert it back, simply go the other way around. Check `bits[i]` and then set `c |= (1<<i)` if you found a `'1'`.